# Exceeding row limit - create new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns on a sheet "list", one column that lists all business entities, the other lists all org units. The functionality of the code below works perfectly but returns an error because it exceeds the sheet row limit.

The data is pasted onto a sheet "cc_act" is there a way to at point of error create a new sheet called "cc_act1"...."cc_act2" until the script is complete?

```
Declare Function HypMenuVRefresh Lib "HsAddin" () As Long
```

Sub cc()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim list As Worksheet: Set list = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("list")
Dim p As Worksheet: Set p = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("p")
Dim calc As Worksheet: Set calc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("calc")
Dim cc As Worksheet: Set cc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("cc_act")
Dim cc_lr As Long
Dim calc_lr As Long: calc_lr = calc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim calc_lc As Long: calc_lc = calc.Cells(1, 
calc.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim calc_rg As Range
Dim ctry_rg As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

list.Activate

For x = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If list.Range("B" & x).Value <> "" Then
            p.Cells(17, 3) = list.Range("B" & x).Value
            End If


        For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If list.Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
                p.Cells(17, 4) = list.Range("A" & i).Value
                p.Calculate
            End If

            p.Activate
            Call HypMenuVRefresh
            p.Calculate

                '''changes country on calc table
                calc.Cells(2, 2) = p.Cells(17, 4)
                calc.Cells(2, 3) = p.Cells(17, 3)
                calc.Calculate
            '''copy the calc range and past under last column
            With calc
            Set calc_rg = calc.Range("A2:F2" & calc_lr)
            End With

            With cc
            cc_lr = cc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            calc_rg.Copy
            cc.Cells(cc_lr, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With

    Next i

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a two-column sheet that exceeds the row limit with a combo of two fields? What version of Excel are you running? Unless you're on XL 2003, you have over a MILLION rows of business entitiy/org unit combos? What kind of business is that? How many business entities do you have? How many org units do you have? If you do the math (correctly), do you end up with over a MILLION results? I find that hard to believe for any business.

Comment: use `Long` as the row counter. `Integer` is not large enough for row counts above 65535 rows

Comment: 186 entities with 369 different units, for each i am pulling 15 expense accounts per month.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are a few ways to handle something like this.  See the code sample below, and adapt it to your specific needs.

```
Sub LongColumnToAFewColumns()
    Dim wsF As Worksheet, WST As Worksheet
    Dim rf As Range, rT As Range
    Dim R As Long, j As Integer

    ' initialize
    Set wsF = ActiveSheet
    Set WST = Sheets.Add
    WST.Name = "Results"

    j = 1

    For R = 1 To wsF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 65536
        wsF.Cells(R, 1).Resize(65536).Copy
        WST.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

WST.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        j = j + 1
    Next R

End Sub
```

As an aside, you may want to consider using MS Access for this kind of thing.  Or, better yet, Python or even R.  Good luck with your project.